# On-Click A-tag with Href, socket gets disconnected

Tags: html, href

I am working on a project using socket.io. I want to give user some links to download a file as

```
<a href="<path>" >Link Name</a>
```

When I click on link to download file, my **socket** gets disconnected.

When I use this

```
<a href="<path>" target="_blank">Link Name</a>
```

it works fine. Any reason why this happens?

Comment: I hope voting down ques doesn't mean you didn't get the problem. Atleast give some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you follow a link within the same window, the current page's environment gets completely torn down, including the entire JavaScript environment in which your code (and socket.io's code) is running. That's why it does this when you click a link to a new page within the current window, but not when you open a new window (`target="_blank"`).

You'll want to look at the various single-page-application techniques, which mostly involve swapping content into the current page using ajax (and updating the hash so the URL is different) without loading an entirely new page into the window.

Comment: Ok, then why my other JS code is working fine but only my socket gets disconnected and is not emitting re-connect event automatically(as it usually do) whenever it gets disconnected.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh: Presumably the new page you're loading contains your JavaScript, hooks up events, etc., etc. Just like just about every other page on the web. But because of the tear-down-and-rebuild, the original socket endpoint is gone, hence the disconnect. If you have a "thick" app that connects to a database on startup, exiting the app and running it again doesn't magically keep the original connection to the database, it closes the old connection and opens a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to target downloads to a hidden `iframe`. This would prevent page reloading:

```
<iframe id="downloadIframe" name="downloadIframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<a href="<path>" target="downloadIframe">Link Name</a>
```

We specify `id` as well as `name` for `iframe` for cross-browser behavior.

Comment: The solution works fine on dextop browsers but it is not working in android webview