# Node.js - socket disconnect event doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

In my Node app, I am using `socket.io` for websocket functionality.

In order to let the client know when the server becomes unavailable, I'm using the following code:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        //show error to client
    });
```

This works fine, but there's a nasty side-effect. Every time I click a link to navigate away from the page (or just reload the page) the message pops up - because the *client* disconnects. I certainly do not wish to display a message saying 'the server is unavailable' every time the visitor clicks a link.

I could put a timeout on the error message, giving the browser time to simply navigate away before the error shows. But you'll admit this is a shabby solution. Also, there would be two problems:

1) the error message would be delayed by the timeout amount in cases when it needs to actually be displayed, leaving the user with a non-functioning app and no notification during that interval

2) it wouldn't work for page reloads (I think)

Anyway, there's gotta be a better way. Right?

Note: this is a problem in Firefox, but not Chrome. Haven't tested other browsers yet. Firefox also displays an error message in the console stating that the websocket connection was interrupted, and I'm inclined to believe these two problems have a common cause. I have read quite a few questions and answers regarding this console error, but none seem to apply to my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've ran into this before.

You want to know when the user is leaving the page, and you don't want to popup an error.

Use `onbeforeunload` to signal when they are leaving, then just set a boolean so that socket.io doesn't trigger an error.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  window.unloading = true;
  return; // don't return a string here or it will pop up asking user if they want to navigate away.
}

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  // setTimeout might be optional depending on when onbeforeunload is called
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (!window.unloading)
      //show error to client 
  }, 10); // 10 ms should be long enough for onbeforeunload, and short enough so your real disconnects don't wait
});
```

on before unload is called when the user tries to navigate away.

normally it's used to call a message asking the user if they wish to navigate away, but you could set a variable that says the disconnect is not in error.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to unnregister the disconnect handler on page navigation.

```
function alertfun(){
    //show error to client
}
socket.on('disconnect', alertfun);

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    socket.removeEventListener('disconnect',alertfun);
}
```

You can have several listeners to same event. Remove the ones which you don't want. You should try this as I am not sure if `disconnect` event is fired before or after `onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem.
What I was doing wrong

```
<a href="<path>" >Link Name</a>
```

How I resolved

```
<a href="<path>" target="_blank">Link Name</a>
```

I had a same query and I got some reasons, hope this will help you. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009218/on-click-a-tag-with-href-socket-gets-disconnected)

Comment: Any way this could work with page reloads, not just link clicks?

Comment: No, it won't work with reload. Read comments of @T.J. Crowder in the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

This post explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24009316/3715815. If you do not use a single-page app approach using angular / backbone / or similar, you will never be able to navigate the page without either opening new pages with target=_blank every time, thus spawning new connections for every window opened, or connecting and disconnecting with a new socket instance on each server refresh without target=blank That is the true story, and there is not any magic tricks you can do.