# How do I download a file in javascript without disconnecting web-sockets or flashing a new tab?

Tags: javascript, websocket, download

After a long running server job, I need to automatically trigger a file download in my user's browser. I also have active websocket connections that I need to maintain in case the user is preforming different tasks in my web app. Originally I was doing this:

```
window.location.replace(downloadLink);
```

However, after that line executed I would miss websocket messages. This question deals with the same problem: [On-Click A-tag with Href, socket gets disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009218/on-click-a-tag-with-href-socket-gets-disconnected)

Then I tried this:

```
window.open(downloadLink, "_blank");
```

However this flashes a new tab open and closes it immediately. Its very jarring if the user was working on something else. I have also tried this:

```
axios.get(downloadLink, { responseType: "blob" }).then((response) => {
  const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const docUrl = document.createElement("a");
  docUrl.href = fileURL;
  docUrl.setAttribute("download", fileName);
  document.body.appendChild(docUrl);
  docUrl.click();
});
```

This works but it downloads the file in the background. This file is very large so I would like the user to be able to see download progress in the downloads bar at the bottom of the page.

Does anyone know how to download a file without disconnecting web-sockets or opening a new tab while still displaying the browsers file download progress?

Comment: I haven't tried it before, but you may be able to use `onDownloadProgress` in `axios` to respond to progress events for that background download.  It doesn't display in the browser's downloads bar, but may give you information about the overall download progress that you can display in the UI.

Comment: build an `<a href="...">` and the `.click()` that, instead of assigning `window.location`, and then the browser will treat it as literally any other download including showing download progress - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834261/740553 has all the details.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried your suggestion. I still do not see download progress. The fetch occurs in the background and then the file appears on the downloads bar at instantly 100%. I would like to be able to see the file downloading

Comment: Which browser? Because neither chrome nor firefox will show a file as "done" unless it's so small it immediately finishes downloading. Both will show the exact same download signals as for any other download.